# Logcat showing link to create index, even though it is created

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

```js
String[] group = {"A+", "B+", "O+", "AB+", "A-", "O-", "B-", "AB-"};
    String[] child = {"19", "18", "17", "16", "15"};
      CollectionReference collectionReference;
    ...................................................
    .....................................................
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ....................................
        groupPosition = intent.getIntExtra("groupPosition", 0);
        childPosition = intent.getIntExtra("childPosition", 0);
      .....................
        getData1();
       ............................
    }
    private void getData1() {
            collectionReference = db.collection(group[groupPosition]);
           collectionReference.whereEqualTo("batch", child[childPosition])
                   .whereEqualTo("status", "Resident").whereGreaterThan("days",120).addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
               @Override
               public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                   if(e!=null){
                       Log.d("Shuvo5", "onEvent: "+e);
                   }
                  ............................
```

I am new to Android. While working with firebase firestore, I need to build a query of three fields. I created the index following a link of a logcat message. 
But building the code again shows results in the same message. I don't understand this, can someone please explain it?

The is the error message:

[image: error message]

This is the database:

[image: database]

Comment: Please add both your code and the error message to your question.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and the exact code that you are using. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for your reply.I found the problem.I have  8 collection named-A+,B+,O+,AB+,O-,A-,B-,AB-.The link creates A,B,O,AB,A-,B-,AB-,O-  collection indexes,means plus sign is not created.I tried manually but same thing happens.I can not find out why plus sign is not created.Please reply.

Comment: @aboger thanks for reply.As I said in previous comment ,the problem now is plus sign is missing while creating the index,but minus sign is still there.